# Safest place to store a password's hash

Tags: c#

I know I need to store it as a hash and then compare the values together, but where should I be sending this hash to compare with later?

Comment: Don't forget to [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

Comment: Please, hammar, don't hurt him.

Answer (score 3):

See the [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class. It uses DPAPI and actually fit for providing mid-level of security. In compbination with [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx), it is good enough for most purposes.

Comment: The `ProtectedData` class says it is for password use, but it seems it supports decryption as well as encryption.  This is not suitable for passwords.  Passwords should use [one-way hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function).

Comment: Well of course. It is the rule of thumbs. I'm suggesting the hash (or even salted hash of the hash of the...) to be protected by `ProtectedData`.

Answer (score 1):

This could help?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter where it's stored. The answer is: whatever makes sense for your application.

This could be whatever other storage mechanisms you've got in place. Consider putting it where the other user-related information is now:

- a database
- the registry (you didn't mention whether this was WinForms or other)
- local storage (Win Phone)
- call a web service

Suggest keeping it where users can't easily get their hands on it. Yes, it's a hash, but there'll be problems when people start messing around with that value. Try keeping it out of sight as best you can.

Answer (score 0):

If you can integrate an existing AuthN/AuthZ mechanism, use it instead of rolling your own.

[OAuth](http://oauth.net/) is such a mechanism.

If you must roll your own, then:

- **Use a database to store your data**
- Secure that database as best you can (get a security company/expert or DBA who knows what they're doing to do this)
- Accept the password as [a `SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx)
- [Use a Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)
- Hash the password in-memory on the server, and compare it to a hash that you've previously stored in your database
- Use a one-way hash function that doesn't have known vulnerabilities, such as [SHA256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)
- Get your hash function implementation from [System.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx)